# How do I have logic in ESRI's popup configs for the Flex api/viewer?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

The popup window config functionality I'm referencing is this... http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#//01m30000002q000000

This is my config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <title>Wind</title>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
            Forecast is valid for {DATA_DATE} UTC
            Wind Direction: {WIND_DIRECTION} degrees
            Wind Speed: {WIND_SPEED} knots
            Wind Chill: {WIND_CHILL} F
        ]]>
    </description>
    <fields>
        <field name="DATA_DATE">
            <format useutc="true" />
        </field> 
        <field name="WIND_DIRECTION"/>         
        <field name="WIND_SPEED"/>
        <field name="WIND_CHILL"/>
    </fields>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that sometimes I want to display N/A for the Wind Chill value. This only occurs when wind chill is -999. Is it possible to display something different than what is in the layer data in this config driven popup? If so, how?

I'd rather not have the column for wind chill be a varchar and have the string "N/A" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to display different text when WIND_CHILL=-999.

The popup config used in the Flex Viewer is based on the PopUpInfo in the ArcGIS API for Flex. The popup description is a "String" - see resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/… - that supports basic HTML - see help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/…. It does not support adding "logic"

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Why is it not possible?

Comment: The popup config used in the Flex Viewer is based on the PopUpInfo in the ArcGIS API for Flex. The popup description is a "String" - see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/portal/supportClasses/PopUpInfo.html#description - that supports basic HTML - see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText. It does not support adding "logic".

Comment: That's unfortunate since the old infoconfig popups have been deprecated, which do give me the power to have logic in the popup windows.